# sqlite3 'insert into' error

Tags: python, sqlite

im getting this error:

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO COURSE (title) VALUES (?)',(title))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 11 supplied.

Here is my code:

```
try:
  cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE COURSE 
                 (course_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
                  title TEXT)""")

except sql.OperationalError, msg:   
  print msg
```

.....

```
def add_course(title):
  try:
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO COURSE (title) VALUES (?)''',(title))    
  except sql.OperationalError, msg:
    print msg,
```

.....

```
add_course('Calculus II')
```

It seams as if it counts each character as a value, but i dont understand why.. i have many tables and they handle strings (TEXT) types properly. The only difference in my other tables is that they take in more than one value.

Comment: sql refers to sqlite3.. i did "import sqlite3 as sql"

Comment: I suppose the data type is passed as character array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing a tuple:

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO COURSE (title) VALUES (?)''',(title,))
```

It's iterating over title.

Comment: That worked!! Thank You!! i've been killing myself over this for hours